# Why do soap bubbles rise?

Tags: bubbles

If I have a soap bubble then it will move rather randomly upwards perhaps due to the initial force from me blowing it, and eventually take ground moving downwards.
[image]

[Another answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69124/what-is-the-physics-behind-a-soap-bubble/69125#69125) to a similar question was

> A bubble, while it still exists, is balanced by three factors:
>
> 1. Surface Tension of the soapy water.
> 2. Internal Pressure applied by the air inside the bubble on the surface.
> 3. Atmospheric Pressure.

Now those factors don't take into account the initial force for the blowing of the bubble and does that really explain why the bubbles rise for some time instead of directly just falling?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The air you exhale is in most circumstance warmer than the ambient air temperature. This is the air that ends up in the bubble. Due to the density difference (hot air rises), the soap bubble will rise. In my experience, bubbles do not keep rising, indefinitely. Thermal equilibrium is quickly reached, and the driving buoyancy force disappears. The gravitational force on the water will pull it downwards, but most likely the bubble bursts before you can observe this.

Comment: Your breath contains more CO2, which makes the air inside heavier.

Comment: @kristjan Interesting thought. Any quick calculation that compares it to the temperature effect?

Comment: @kristjan - yes and more water vapour (mass 18) less than other components (and less oxygen (mass 32)) - this is a very interesting point.

Comment: @tom - In exhaled air (according to some sources), there is ~4% CO2. However, it seems that water vapor pressure will pretty much be just saturated to the maximum possible value. However, if the gas inside cools, it might start condensing out, making the bubble even heavier. It is very hard to estimate the effect of H2O on the bubble.

Comment: I don't know whether it really matters, but CO2 might also diffuse away from the bubble. This might happen, because the the bubble is very thin and probably allows diffusion to practically equalize the composition of the air in the inside air layer of the bubble film and the outside layer. Probably the limiting factor of this diffusion is the internal mixing of the gas, that has to bring the CO2 rich air in contact with the bubble's film.

Comment: ~4% CO2 seems a bit high (and [the part of the Wikipedia article that claims it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breathing#Composition) does not contain any sources). It might or might not be the number for a 20 seconds breathholding and is thus not representative.

Comment: Our  breath is 16% oxygen and only 4% CO2

Comment: So the greenhouse effect should make the bubble keep rising! :-P